# How will the new Internet Neutrality Act affect Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain, client, network, politics

How do you think the neutrality act that is being talked about as I write this post will affect the Bitcoin community. Not only in transactions, but mining, how will it affect Bitcoin economically with users and miners alike all on the same network? Can someone give the pros/cons to this question. Also, how could this propel bitcoin positively in anyway? This could affect the whole world but I feel like it could have a huge affect on Bitcoin more than what people think.

Answer (score 1):

> The Internet is a vital platform for innovation, economic growth and
>   free expression in America. And yet, despite two prior FCC attempts,
>   there are no rules on the books to prevent broadband providers from
>   limiting Internet openness by blocking content or discriminating
>   against consumers and entrepreneurs online.
>   —Protecting and Promoting the Open Internet May 15, 2014 fcc.gov

There's a possibility that Internet Service Providers discriminate against bitcoin traffic either by making it more difficult, setting limits, charging a toll, or by blocking it altogether. This could prevent nodes from relaying transactions and relaying blocks, either of which would undermine the network.

The prodigiously talented members of the community would no doubt come up with  workarounds, perhaps ways of obfuscating bitcoin related traffic. This could possibly result in an arms race. It could ultimately drive the bitcoin community to build its own network which some have already proposed.